# Dropbox picture sync: Skip RAW files?

Tags: windows, osx, synchronization, dropbox

I like the convenience of having Dropbox keep track of my photos because it tends to work with my devices over 3G (I am often tethering to my phone with my iPad and Macbook) as well as Wifi, but it's a waste of network traffic to sync the raw files from my camera or memory card. It clutters up the dropbox list and the files are just huge.

Is there a way to configure the Dropbox client so that it ignores a certain file extension for  the picture sync?

Also, I suspect that if I just go and delete the raw files, that the next time I plug in the memory card and tell Dropbox to sync, it will re-download the raw files. Which would be terribad.

I could switch to iCloud for Photo Stream, I suppose, but there will be no access via 3G that way. And I've already got years of experience with Dropbox so I *know* it's going to just work. I think any method that works for filtering files to exclude from sync on Dropbox in general should work here too.

Edit: Wow there are 19k votes for [this exact request](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/2385/option-to-exclude-by-file-extension).

Comment: Please comment if you vote to close.

Comment: It seems you can answer this question yourself now.

Comment: Users are never required to comment if they vote to close, and in your case it's a pending vote do move to [webapps.SE]

Comment: It seems like the right thing to do at this juncture is not have my camera generate any RAW files... Dropbox doesn't want me to be judicious about excluding filetypes.

Comment: You can choose "[Selective Sync](https://www.dropbox.com/help/175/en)" to not have certain folders synced. Perhaps you can put the RAW files in one folder and the other image files in a different folder.

Comment: Yup that would work if I needed those files for whatever reason. The thing is, Dropbox will automatically load all the files...

Comment: This is not a question about a Web Application.